# HttpClient not handling body after redirect

Tags: micronaut

I am using an HttpClient (part of micronaut 2.2.0) to perform a GET to a resource that redirects from a Controller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    @Client("https://www.vrt.be/") @Inject
    RxHttpClient client;

    @Get
    public String getIt() {
        return client.toBlocking().retrieve("/");
    }
}
```

I am running this app via SAM CLI with a template that has a lambda function and an API gateway. When issuing a `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/` it throws an exception. This exception also happens when deploying the template to AWS itself.

```
19:38:58.007 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: GET /
19:38:58.008 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: www.vrt.be(-1)
19:38:58.023 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - host: www.vrt.be
19:38:58.023 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
19:38:58.873 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received for Request: GET https://www.vrt.be/
19:38:58.873 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
19:38:58.874 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
19:38:58.874 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Length: 230
19:38:58.874 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Connection: close
19:38:58.874 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2020 20:19:06 GMT
19:38:58.874 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Cache-Control: max-age=604800
19:38:58.875 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Location: https://www.vrt.be/nl/
19:38:58.875 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Vary: Accept-Encoding
19:38:58.875 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
...
19:38:58.876 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
19:38:58.876 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
19:38:58.876 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.vrt.be/nl/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

19:38:58.877 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-1] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
19:38:58.989 [main] ERROR i.m.f.a.p.AbstractLambdaContainerHandler - Error while handling request
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Error decoding HTTP response body: No request present
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2148)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2021)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with my use of the HttpClient or if this is an actual issue in the implementation of HttpClient.

Comment: Can you prepare and share a [mcve]? It looks like `*.client.follow-redirects` configuration is set to false somewhere, but it's hard to tell without seeing a specific example.

Comment: I have debugged it as far as I could and the redirect is followed. Things go wrong when the request for the redirect is issued. Anyway, see https://github.com/kristofvb/mn-issue-demo to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Create the file

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/io.micronaut.http.HttpResponseFactory
```

with the following content:

```
io.micronaut.http.simple.SimpleHttpResponseFactory
```

It will register an additional `HttpResponseFactory` that will be used by any internal HTTP request.

### Why the problem exists?

By default, the Micronaut function application registers a single `HttpResponseFactory` service called [`MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory`](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-aws/blob/v2.2.3/function-aws-api-proxy/src/main/java/io/micronaut/function/aws/proxy/model/factory/MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory.java). It is designed to handle AWS API responses and delegate all other responses to the alternative `HttpResponseFactory` stored in the `ALTERNATE` static field. This field gets initialized by the `SoftServiceLoader` that checks if there are any other instances registered in any `META-INF/services/io.micronaut.http.HttpResponseFactory` file.

The problem with your exemplary application starts in the [`DefaultHttpClient`, line 2072](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/2.2.x/http-client/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/client/netty/DefaultHttpClient.java#L2072). Here, we can find the `redirectExchange` flowable object that represents a redirection. It gets published to the event loop, and it defines (using the `first()` method) that it should return the result of the redirected request or `HttpStatus.notFound()` if the redirection does not emit any value in return.

Now, if you look at the bottom of the stack trace, you will find this:

```
Caused by: io.micronaut.http.server.exceptions.InternalServerException: No request present
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.model.factory.MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory.status(MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.HttpResponseFactory.status(HttpResponseFactory.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse.notFound(HttpResponse.java:105)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2059)
    ... 51 more
```

It shows what exactly causes the exception - it is [`io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse.notFound()`](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/2.2.x/http/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/HttpResponse.java#L104-L106). If we look at the implementation of that method, we will find this:

```java
static <T> MutableHttpResponse<T> notFound() {
    return HttpResponseFactory.INSTANCE.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

The `HttpResponseFactory.INSTANCE` variable returns the factory registered by the service loader, which in our case is `MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory`.

Now let's take a look at how does `MicronautAwsProxyResponseFactory` implement the `status(status,reason)` method:

```java
@Override
public <T> MutableHttpResponse<T> status(HttpStatus status, String reason) {
    final HttpRequest<Object> req = ServerRequestContext.currentRequest().orElse(null);
    if (req instanceof MicronautAwsProxyRequest) {
        final MicronautAwsProxyResponse<T> response = (MicronautAwsProxyResponse<T>) ((MicronautAwsProxyRequest<Object>) req).getResponse();
        return response.status(status, reason);
    } else {
        if (ALTERNATE != null) {
            return ALTERNATE.status(status, reason);
        } else {
            throw new InternalServerException("No request present");
        }
    }
}
```

The current request is not an instance of the `MicronautAwsProxyRequest`, so the flow goes to the `else` branch. Here we get `ALTERNATE` that is not set, and that is why the exception is thrown.

When you register `io.micronaut.http.simple.SimpleHttpResponseFactory` in the service loader, the above flow will not throw an exception, and the result of `ALTERNATE.status(status,reason)` will be returned.

This corner case is not easy to detect, especially that other modules like `http-server-netty` register its own `HttpResponseFactory`, and everything works. For instance, if you would add `http-server-netty` dependency to your project, it would work without any issue because it registers `io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpResponseFactory` which handles all statuses without throwing an exception.

I guess that a module like `micronaut-http-client` could potentially register this `io.micronaut.http.simple.SimpleHttpResponseFactory` for the service loader out of the box, but that's the question to the Micronaut dev team. It could, however, introduce some side effects, so I would just register this factory for the service loader in the application.

PS: If you want to debug your problem, you can run a unit test like the one below with the debugger.

```java
package demo;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.testutils.AwsProxyRequestBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.testutils.MockLambdaContext;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaContainerHandler;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ExampleControllerTest {

    static MicronautLambdaContainerHandler handler;

    static Context lambdaContext = new MockLambdaContext();

    static {
        try {
            handler = new MicronautLambdaContainerHandler(
                    ApplicationContext.build()
            );
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        AwsProxyRequestBuilder builder = new AwsProxyRequestBuilder("/", HttpMethod.GET.toString());

        AwsProxyResponse response = handler.proxy(builder.build(), lambdaContext);

        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I should have dug deeper.

Comment: You're welcome! I added a unit test example that may help you if you run into some issues with executing serverless functions. You can write a similar one and attach a debugger to get inside the execution.